# How to use Caliburn Micro's EventAggregator to send empty events (no payload)?

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I found [articles](https://blog.davidpadbury.com/2010/01/01/empty-type-parameters/) about and [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430059/publish-an-event-without-payload-in-prism-eventaggregator) to this question pertaining to Prism, but I didn't find anything pertaining to Caliburn Micro. I checked *all* questions here tagged with `Caliburn.Micro` and `EventAggregator`, but didn't find anything Caliburn specific about this seemingly basic issue.

**Scenario:** I want to publish events to the `EventAggregator` that don't have any information, other than signaling that something happened.

**Problem:** First, in Caliburn Micro, the `EventAggregator`'s `Publish()` method requires an instance of a type to be sent. Second, subscribing and handling events require the implementation of the `IHandle<T>` interface, where `T` is the type of instances that we want to receive. It seems that this is fully designed around publishing and handling actual data.

**Goal:** To be able to publish simple events without having to create and instantiate multiple empty/dummy classes, and without having to `Handle()` unnecessary events that I need to filter further with conditionals.

---

## My solution so far

This is what I want to improve/replace. (Obviously, this solution is problematic because it creates tighter coupling around the concrete classes, but in my use case this is not a big issue, since it's a small project with singular publishing components for a given event, and the EventAggregator serves other practical goals.)

I made a generic `Signal<T>` class that implements the singleton pattern, providing a static instance of itself through the `Instance` property:

```
public class Signal<T>
{
    public static readonly Signal<T> Instance = new Signal<T>();

    private Signal() { }
}
```

So I can publish events in the following way (`SignalSourceClass` is an example):

```
_eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(Signal<SignalSourceClass>.Instance);
```

And handle events by declaring the implementation of `IHandle<T>` in the following way:

```
IHandle<Signal<SignalSourceClass>>
```

This way I can send and receive "empty" events by creating only this single `Signal` class. (Of course this is a limited solution, since components can only send one event this way.)

**I suspect that this solution is primitive (well, let's just call it a fact), and that there is something better that I'm overlooking.**

Comment: are you looking to have a type associated with the event? I guess you could also send "" as well. _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread("");

Comment: Yes, I'd like the events to be identifiable in some way, and to implement IHandle<T> and Handle() in a way that doesn't necessitate additional "if" checks in the receiving classes (e.g. they are not receiving events that are useless for them). If I could use the sender of the event, that would be perfect in this small project. Maybe I should try to decorate the EventAggregator class with additional functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a enum with all possible signals you want:

```
public enum ProjectSignals
{
    Connected,
    Disconnected,
    Openned
}
```

then just

```
_eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread( ProjectSignals.Connected );
```

and

```
class SomeClass : IHandle<ProjectSignals>
{
   public void Handle( ProjectSignals signal )
   {
        switch (signal)
        {
            case Connected:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I could avoid somehow that switch? (And only receive e.g. ProjectSignals.Connected.) I'll upvote your answer definitely, but I ran out of votes for today. :)

Comment: Not directly. The publish is based on the type of the object. You could create a single enum per thing you want to catch. One for connected, one for Disconnected, and so on.

Comment: Yes, that would be definitely viable, but similarly to the empty classes, the empty enums look a bit bizarre; I was hoping for something that "feels right". Not sure though if this is the right attitude in this case. :)

Comment: I guess the point of using enums is that its lighter weight, slightly less memory pressure.

Comment: Yes, you're right. If it's okay, I'll leave it open for now; maybe I can find or come up with some decoration of the EventAggregator class that can solve it neatly. But I'll definitely come back to upvote tomorrow.